# How can i store a bunch of jquery commands in a function that i can call with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Currently i have this:

```
$(".splitCol").click(function () { 
          $.cookie('whichColumn', 'split'); 
          $(".threeCol .active").removeClass("active"); 
          $(".leftCol .active").removeClass("active"); 
          $(".splitCol span").addClass("active"); 

          $(".threeColumns li:eq(3)").removeClass("first");
          $(".threeColumns li:eq(6)").removeClass("first");

          $(".entries").removeClass("threeColumns");
          $(".entries").removeClass("leftColumn");
          $(".entries").addClass("splitColumns"); 

          $(".splitColumns li:eq(2)").addClass("first");
          $(".splitColumns li:eq(4)").addClass("first");
          $(".splitColumns li:eq(6)").addClass("first");
          $(".splitColumns li:eq(8)").css("display", "none");
     });
```

And i need to repeat all those commands again after i do an if check. How can i take all those and add them to a single function so that if you $(".splitCol").click(function () { then it runs the function. And then also if the IF statement is satisfied it runs it as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract your current anonymous callback function to a normal function:

In your click event binding:

```
$(".splitCol").click(function () {
  originalFunction();

  // The if statement you talk about...
  if (condition) {
    originalFunction();
  }
  //...
});


// extracted function
function originalFunction() { // please change the function name
  $.cookie('whichColumn', 'split'); 
  $(".threeCol .active").removeClass("active"); 
  $(".leftCol .active").removeClass("active"); 
  $(".splitCol span").addClass("active"); 

  $(".threeColumns li:eq(3)").removeClass("first");
  $(".threeColumns li:eq(6)").removeClass("first");

  $(".entries").removeClass("threeColumns");
  $(".entries").removeClass("leftColumn");
  $(".entries").addClass("splitColumns"); 

  $(".splitColumns li:eq(2)").addClass("first");
  $(".splitColumns li:eq(4)").addClass("first");
  $(".splitColumns li:eq(6)").addClass("first");
  $(".splitColumns li:eq(8)").css("display", "none");
}
```

**Note:** If your extracted function uses the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/this_Operator) keyword, for example to get a reference to the element that triggered the click event, you should call it in a different way to preserve the context:

```
// in your click callback:
originalFunction.call(this); // preserve the context
```

Comment: +1 for the note about call(). I've been working in javascript for years and only just learned about call() while reading the jQuery source three days ago!

Answer (score 2):

Separate it out like this:

```
function clickHandler()
{
  $.cookie('whichColumn', 'split');
  $(".threeCol .active").removeClass("active");
  $(".leftCol .active").removeClass("active");
  $(".splitCol span").addClass("active");
  $(".threeColumns li:eq(3)").removeClass("first");
  $(".threeColumns li:eq(6)").removeClass("first");
  $(".entries").removeClass("threeColumns");
  $(".entries").removeClass("leftColumn");
  $(".entries").addClass("splitColumns");
  $(".splitColumns li:eq(2)").addClass("first");
  $(".splitColumns li:eq(4)").addClass("first");
  $(".splitColumns li:eq(6)").addClass("first");
  $(".splitColumns li:eq(8)").css("display", "none")
}

$(".splitCol").click(clickHandler);
```

You can use any anonymous function as your event handler.  Bear in mind that the `this` keyword, when used in such a function, will refer to the DOM element being clicked.

Answer (score 2):

That you have to re-run all that suggests that you may have a larger code structure problem (can't tell without seeing the rest of your code). You may want to revisit the flow/structure of your code.

Also, you've already put all of that code into a function - notice the function(). You can take that function block, put it elsewhere, name it, and then pass the name to click().

Also, for more efficient (less lookups) turn

```
$(".entries").removeClass("threeColumns");
$(".entries").removeClass("leftColumn");
$(".entries").addClass("splitColumns");
```

into

```
$(".entries").removeClass("threeColumns").removeClass("leftColumn").addClass("splitColumns");
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript in the DOM is largely event-based programming.  So think like an event-based programmer and... do it with events!

Also, I took the liberty of applying some efficiency measures to your jQuery

```
$(".splitCol")
  .bind( 'your-custom-event-name', (function ()
  { 
    $.cookie('whichColumn', 'split');

    $(".threeCol, .leftCol")
    .find(".active")
    .removeClass("active");

    $(".splitCol span")
      .addClass("active");

    $(".threeColumns")
      .find("li:eq(3), li:eq(6)")
      .removeClass("first");

    $(".entries")
      .removeClass("threeColumns leftColumn")
      .addClass("splitColumns");

    $( ".splitColumns" )
      .find("i:even:not(li:eq(0),li:eq(8))")
      .addClass("first")
      .end()
      .find( "li:eq(8)" )
      .css("display", "none");
  } )
  .click( function()
  {
    $(this).trigger( 'your-custom-event-name' );
  } );
```

And then you can trigger this custom event from anywhere else

```
if ( /* whatever */ )
{
  $(".splitCol").trigger( 'your-custom-event-name' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Highly inspired by [David Andres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418699/how-can-i-store-a-bunch-of-jquery-commands-in-a-function-that-i-can-call-with-cli/1418709#1418709) and [ravidgemole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418699/how-can-i-store-a-bunch-of-jquery-commands-in-a-function-that-i-can-call-with-cli/1418711#1418711) :D**

```
var clickHandler = function(statement) {
  $.cookie('whichColumn', 'split');
  $(".threeCol, .leftCol").find(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(".splitCol span").addClass("active");
  $(".threeColumns").find("li:(6), li:eq(3)").removeClass("first");
  $(".entries").removeClass("threeColumns leftColumn").addClass("splitColumns");
  $(".splitColumns").find("li:nth-child(8-2n)").addClass("first")
        .end().find('li:eq(8)').hide();
  if (statement) {
    clickHandler(false);
  }      
};
// statement = ( 15 == 16 );
$(".splitCol").click(function(){
  clickHandler(statement);
});;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code above does not work, namelt the find("li:6), li stuff doesn't seem to be catching on.